# Ubuntu doesn't login after broken update

Tags: updates, bug-reporting

Unfortunately, I made the foolish mistake of shutting down my computer by force while it was updating. So here's how I proceeded after (cause I did my search and nothing's working so far) :

- I tried the `apt-get update` command
- I tried changing the authority of `/home` to my user
- I booted in recovery mode and clicked on '`dpkg repair broken packages`'
- I tried the `boot-repair tool` So none of it works, and I can't log in from the graphic interface ( all of the commands I did were used after I entered `Ctrl+Alt+F1` )
- I also tried installing another graphic version installed gnome , it was perfectly installed but the same problem kept showing, I had no access to my session , and whenever I enter the login and password it bugs and shows a "`system program problem`" then returns to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

**Considering every solution doesn't work at this point and that you want to keep your Windows files** : I would probably recommend making a backup of important files (or those you want to keep) using a Ubuntu LiveUSB and moving the files to a cloud-based service (e.g. Google Drive or Dropbox)

Comment: So it's a dead end ? :D

Comment: Seems like it, at least for me... Sorry :(

Answer (score -1):

May be your account config failed somewhere, If there is nothing important on that account. You can try create new user by :

```
sudo adduser username
```

And then you should try to login normally. If you can't login with gnome or Unity, try i3, it's a beaultiful and powerfull tiling windows manager which you should.

Comment: The thing is, that user is connected directly to my windows partition so it has all my windows files in addition to my Ubuntu files :/

Comment: Have you tried update your system

Comment: Yes I did and didn't solve it

Comment: You should try refresh ubuntu as default installed

Comment: Sorry, how can I do that ?

Comment: Hey. If you can access via terminal. You should backup your windows file first. After that, you can try anyway. If you can't solve. just reinstall ubuntu. :)

Comment: Very true, cause looking at it as it is now re-installing is only what's left

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help I'll search a bit more, if I can find sth better than just re-installing